# Access android device from a different android device on the same network

Tags: android

Suppose, I have two android devices A and B. They are on the same wifi network. Device A does not have any **password or pattern** lock and It is **rooted**.

**How can I access to device A from device B and view it's files?**

I know that using reverse_tcp or installing some kind of .apk in the target device which will create a backdoor connection to my device will somehow allow me to access in the target device. But, I don't want to do it in that way.

I want to know a way to access device A from device B remotely where I don't need to do anything with device A and still gain access to it's system.**Is it possible? Can adb shell commands help me to do it?** Assume both are my devices and I have full access control on both devices. I just want to control one using the other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB to connect to A over network the same way you do via USB. All you have to do is switch adbd on A to tcpip mode. See: [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

If you want to do this over WiFi, first connect A to a PC via USB, then fetch the current IP address of A:

```
adb shell ip -f inet addr show wlan0
192.168.1.111  # example
```

Next tell A's adbd to switch to tcpip mode and listen for connections on some port, for instance 5555.

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Then from any device (whether PC or your device B) on the same network you can establish an ADB session with A by running:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.111:5555
```

Neither A nor B need to be rooted for this to work. You do need USB debugging access to A to enable ADB over TCP. Furthermore, the two devices do need to be on the same network. If A is NAT/firewalled and B isn't, then you'll need to open ports, etc.

Comment: Result shows 'restarting in tcp mode' and then nothing happens, the cursor keeps blinking. What am I doing wrong? My device is rooted, USB Debugging is enabled.

Comment: Nothing more is supposed to happen. You should proceed to the next step: `adb connect`.

Comment: No, I mean I can not give any command, The cursor keeps blinking, it does not take any command. Whatever I write nothing appears in the command window. I have tried port forwarding. Then it says that I have more than one device or emulator connected.

Comment: My daemon started in port 5037. Should I try to connect in this port instead of port 5555 ?

Comment: I have disabled my Local Area Network of my PC and then tried to connect. This time adb is restarting in TCP mode successfully but when I try to connect, it shows 'unable to connect to 10.0.0.7:5555: cannot connect to 10.0.0.7:5555: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (10051)'. My android device is connected to wifi network.